# Identify this dinosaur build

Tags: set-identification

I acquired a random lot of LEGO bricks and came across this small dinosaur build. I can't find it anywhere. Pictured is about 35 pieces, but It is probably incomplete because even this had been broken in 2 parts.

Includes 4 dark green cheese wedges and 2 lime inverse 2x2 45 degree slopes and 2 white eye print 1x1 round tiles. Searching through sets that include those parts however did not help me.

Is this an official build? It seems a bit too polished to be just some kid's MOC.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creative Supplement Set No: 10693-1
[image]

Searched on the curved green slope (the tail)

Comment: thanks you! I can't believe I missed that!